# How to get all objects created by currently signed in user from DynamoDB in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

Sorry if this is a very beginner question, I've tried everything but I can't figure this out. I created an AWS Amplify project with Amplify Auth enabled, and added a RESTful API that connects to a DynamoDB database. When I configured the DB through the CLI, I added columns for item_name and quantity. I made a working POST request function in my code and was able to add items to the DB, and noticed that the DB automatically added a column for userId, which had the IDs in the form of 'us-east-1:49h78684-ac99-4da8-1947-1414bf155e4d'. I wanted to make a GET request to fetch all items from the DB that were created by the currently logged-in user. So I figured that I would use this function:

```
const getUserId = async () => {
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    const cognitoUserId = user.attributes.sub;
    return cognitoUserId;
  }
```

to get the current user's ID and filter the DB with that ID to fetch all their items. However, this function returns an ID in the form of '0448f4d8-6061-5735-36c9-e64fce15a2c4', which doesn't match the DB's userID. I also searched the `user`'s attributes to find the correct matching userId, but couldn't find anything that matched the format of the DB's userID.

I don't know if I'm approaching this wrong entirely, or if there is a different way to get the proper userID of the current user, but all I want is to be able to make a GET request for all the items created by the currently logged in user. Any help would greatly be appreciated.